# Repeating xml nodes into separate blocks

Tags: php, xml

**I have an xml like this:**

```
<products>
 <product>
 <name>ad</name>
 <category>something</category>
 ...
    <size>S</size>
    <color-code>87-3</color-code>
    <size-code>24294</size-code>
    <size-qty>10</size-qty>
    <size-codeproducer>5902228002604</size-codeproducer>
    <size>M</size>
    <color-code>87-4</color-code>
    <size-code>24295</size-code>
    <size-qty>64</size-qty>
    <size-codeproducer>5902228002611</size-codeproducer>
    <size>L</size>
    <color-code>87-5</color-code>
    <size-code>24296</size-code>
    <size-qty>46</size-qty>
    <size-codeproducer>5902228002628</size-codeproducer>
    <size>XXL</size>
    <color-code>87-7</color-code>
    <size-code>24298</size-code>
    <size-qty>0</size-qty>
    <size-codeproducer>5902228002635</size-codeproducer>
  </product>
  <product>
  ...
  ...
  ...
  </product>
</products>
```

Well I want to separate those repeating nodes of `<size>`,`<color-code>` and others **like:**

```
<product>
<name>ad</name>
<category>something</category>
...
<variation>
   <size>S</size>
   <color-code>87-3</color-code>
   <size-code>24294</size-code>
   <size-qty>10</size-qty>
   <size-codeproducer>5902228002604</size-codeproducer>
</variation>
<variation>
   <size>M</size>
   <color-code>87-4</color-code>
   <size-code>24295</size-code>
   <size-qty>64</size-qty>
   <size-codeproducer>5902228002611</size-codeproducer>
</variation>
<variation>
   <size>L</size>
   <color-code>87-5</color-code>
   <size-code>24296</size-code>
   <size-qty>46</size-qty>
   <size-codeproducer>5902228002628</size-codeproducer>
</variation>
<variation>
   <size>XXL</size>
   <color-code>87-7</color-code>
   <size-code>24298</size-code>
   <size-qty>0</size-qty>
   <size-codeproducer>5902228002635</size-codeproducer>
</variation>
```

And I can't really think of a good logic to do that. I'm using php, first thing that I though was using arrays and checking if the node exists, and always checking if the size node exists - if it does to create a new array. Whats the best and easiest approach here?

Comment: A better approach would be using XSLT-2.0. It would be easy and straightforward with it. Can you use XSLT-2.0?

Comment: nope, I need to write a re-parser for this xml, because the import tool won't work with anything else except the different variations.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose langauge (like SQL) designed to transform XML files such as your specific end-use needs. Like many general-purpose languages, PHP can run XSLT 1.0  as a lower level layer using special libraries (similar to how it runs SQL), namely [php-xsl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class (requires the .ini extension enabled).

Specifically, the below XSLT rewrites each *product* node by looping through each *size* (assuming it will always begin the *variation* grouping) to retrieve corresponding nodes at the same occurrence.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="products">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="product"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="product">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="prod_pos" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="name|category"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="size">
                <variation>
                    <xsl:variable name="size_occur" select="position()"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="/products/product[$prod_pos]/color-code[$size_occur]"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="/products/product[$prod_pos]/size-code[$size_occur]"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="/products/product[$prod_pos]/size-qty[$size_occur]"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="/products/product[$prod_pos]/size-codeproducer[$size_occur]"/>
                </variation>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP**

```
// Load the XML source and XSLT file
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load('Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// Configure transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// Transform XML source
$newXML = new DOMDocument;
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);
echo $newXML;

// Save output to file
$xmlfile = 'Output.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXML);
```

**Output**

```
<products>
   <product>
      <name>ad</name>
      <category>something</category>
      <variation>
         <size>S</size>
         <color-code>87-3</color-code>
         <size-code>24294</size-code>
         <size-qty>10</size-qty>
         <size-codeproducer>5902228002604</size-codeproducer>
      </variation>
      <variation>
         <size>M</size>
         <color-code>87-4</color-code>
         <size-code>24295</size-code>
         <size-qty>64</size-qty>
         <size-codeproducer>5902228002611</size-codeproducer>
      </variation>
      <variation>
         <size>L</size>
         <color-code>87-5</color-code>
         <size-code>24296</size-code>
         <size-qty>46</size-qty>
         <size-codeproducer>5902228002628</size-codeproducer>
      </variation>
      <variation>
         <size>XXL</size>
         <color-code>87-7</color-code>
         <size-code>24298</size-code>
         <size-qty>0</size-qty>
         <size-codeproducer>5902228002635</size-codeproducer>
      </variation>
   </product>
</products>
```

[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWe/4)

Comment: updated the question - as there are more product nodes each of the  product node color code is being copied into different variations.

Comment: See update, now accounting for *product* as child to root, *products*. FYI - always include root tags in XML posts.